# Regular expression for parsing authors information from a scientic article

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to create a tool with which I could parse some text automaticaly.
I am using javascript and regular expressions.

For example, I have this text:

```
Aa Aaa 1, Bb Bbb 2  and Cc Ccc 1
1 Institut xx Xx, Some University, Xxxx 14, US-10000 NewYork, USA; E-Mails: aa.aaa@edu.com; cc.ccc@edu.com
2 Institut zz Zzz, Some University2, Zzzz 20, US-10000 NewYork, USA; E-Mail: bb.bbb@edu.com
```

And I would like to parse those informations

For each author (FirstName and LastName):

- The affiliation
- The email address

So in my example, I would like to have:

```
Aa Aaa - Institut xx Xx, Some University, Xxxx 14, US-10000 NewYork, USA - aa.aaa@edu.com

Bb Bbb - Institut zz Zzz, Some University2, Zzzz 20, US-10000 NewYork, USA - bb.bbb@edu.com

Cc Ccc - Institut xx Xx, Some University, Xxxx 14, US-10000 NewYork, USA - cc.ccc@edu.com
```

It looks very coplicated, so if I think that I shuld separate my question in few simpler questions, let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't do everything with regex, believe it or not, I tried once to build a nuclear bomb with javascript and regex, but it didn't work for some unknown reason. :(

Comment: Provided the citation style used is consistent, this should not be a problem. In the general case, however, parsing paper citations is a non-trivial problem, not solvable by means of regular expressions, but calling for advanced natural language processing methods.

Comment: Of course, these are not exactly citations, but they're similar in nature and will probably pose similar challenges.

Comment: @gdoron thank you for your answer. I am assuming that it looks complicated and not easy to create but I think that it shuld be possible. The text which needs to be parsed has some regular rools and I think that it can be possible to use them for this.

Comment: @Ana. If there are rules about the text, you should mention them. A large example of text is better.

Comment: Actually, now that I look closer at the problem, I definitely wouldn't use a regex here. It should be easy enough to split the first line by commas and 'and', then extract the institution reference from each one and identify the corresponding email.

Comment: @gdoron. In fact, we can see the rules in the example I gived. We have authors with after them a number. This number is the number of the affiliation. In the affiliation we can find the email which contains the first and last name of the author. Each author is separated by coma, except the last one which is separated by "and"

Comment: @MikhailKozhevnikov. I think that your idea is realy good. I will try to implement something similar to this. If you have some more precize ideas, thank you.

Comment: Surely there may be University or department names that include commas ...

Comment: @Pointy, yes but the authors are allways on the first line and have a number at the end.

Comment: @Pointy there're no department names in the first line, as far as i understand

Comment: @MikhailKozhevnikov, exactly, you're right

Comment: Unless the order of the authors e-mails will always be the same as the order listed at the top, I don't think you can reliably figure out which e-mail belongs to which author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It is doable task.*

*I don't code in JavaScript, but I hope someone from SO will clone the following Perl code for you:*

```
$_ = "\n\n" . $input;
1 while s/^(.*?\n?)\n{1,2}\s*([^\d]+)\s+(\d+)\s*?(?:\s*and|[,\n\s])(.*?)(?<=\n)(\3\s+)([^\n]*)(\n.*$|$)/$1$2 - $6\n\n$4$5$6$7/gs;
s/\n\n.*$//s;
print $_;
```

*See and test the Perl code [here](http://ideone.com/10c72).*